# How to use Contains method in Expression Class in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, expression

Here is my code as following:

```
    protected Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetLambdaForField(string SearchTxtBox)
    {
        // Build a Lamda expression to get the Node headers for this sub master.
        ConstantExpression constForeignKeyID = Expression.Constant(SearchTxtBox);

        ParameterExpression paramEntity =
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

        MemberExpression mex =
            LambdaExpression.PropertyOrField(paramEntity, DefaultSearchFieldName);

        BinaryExpression filter = Expression.Equal(mex, constForeignKeyID);

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> exprLambda =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filter,
            new ParameterExpression[] { paramEntity });

        return exprLambda;
    }
```

I have used `Expression.Equal(...);` but this is not what I actually wanted to achieve.
I wanted something like the `Expression.Contains` method (so that it can find the record with partial information without having me to enter the complete value).

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what the purpose of this function is? Its unclear to me what you are actually wanting to do.

Comment: Hi Brayan, Got the answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [Expression.Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var filter = Expression.Call(mex, 
    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), 
    constForeignKeyID);
```

This is equal to the following expression:

```
x => x.Prop.Contains(searchString)
```

Hope this helps.